# Best way to pass a guid from a javascript function as a value not a reference?

Tags: javascript

I have a function to generate guids for testing:

```
helpers.guid = function(){
  var guid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
      var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
       return v.toString(16);
  });   
  return guid;
};
```

I call it with:

```
var thisTest.guid1 = helpers.guid();
var thisTest.guid2 = helpers.guid();
```

The problem is each time I refer to thisTest.guid1 it's a different guid.  I need to set the object property to a permanent value and I'm not sure how to do that.  I've tried adding a closure but couldn't get it to work.

**Edit:** to clarify, i need to be able to generate multiple guids and assign each one to a different variable.  Right now each time I refer to a variable i get a new guid as it presumably calls the function again and returns a new value.  I need "guid1" and "guid2" to be the same values each time then are used.

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/RGu4p/

Comment: Or possibly "better": http://jsfiddle.net/RGu4p/1/ . This example only generates the guid when it's first needed. My first example executes immediately and holds that value forever

Comment: "var thisTest.guid = helpers.guid();" throws error. I copy pasted your code, fixed thisTest variable and there is no issue as you describe, thisTest.guid is actually a string, not a function http://jsfiddle.net/VV3rN/

Comment: I hope you understand this is actually not a real GUID...

Comment: `thisTest.guid` above does *not* references a function. It references the return value of a function.

Comment: Yup, edited to add "return value" of a function.  Also don't need a "real" non-random guid, this is just for testing purposes with mocha.  I do need the format and to avoid collisions.

Comment: _The problem is each time I refer to thisTest.guid1 it's a different guid._ __No it isn't.__ How are you referencing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question title is much simpler than unnecessarily complicated code example and text with it ... Let's use much simpler code.

```
var seed = 1 ;
function generate () {
    return seed++ ;
}
      var a = generate() ;    
alert(a + "\n" + a + "\n" + a ) ;
```

This of course shows "1" three times ... And it will, regardless of is it an object property or a variable. Return value of the function is kept in the memory because it is referenced by the variable a. Object property of course will behave the same:

```
var a = { b : generate() }; 
       alert( a.b + "\n" + a.b + "\n" + a.b ) ;
```

This will show "1" three times again. Likewise each call to generate() will yield new value.

```
var a = {b:generate(), c:generate(), d:generate() }; 
alert( a.b + "\n" + a.c + "\n" + a.d ) ;
```

This will output "1", "2" and "3". Each call to function returns a value which is referenced by different object property, thus we have three different values.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly you could use 2 functions:

> 1 - a function to generate the GUID and then store it somewhere, like
>   in a hidden control somewhere on your form, so you can get it later
>
> 2- a function that retrieves the value of your hidden control.